# Get text from terminal window using WM_GETTEXT

Tags: delphi, winapi, pascal, win32gui, delphi-10-seattle

I'm trying to get text from terminal window.

https://www.attachmate.com/products/extra/

it looks like below:

[image]

I'm using WM_GETTEXT to get text from this terminal window. As you can see above, the window has text (in green) but i'm not able to get anything, even after trying out all windows and child windows under this applications.

the code i use is:

```
function TForm1.fn_get_text(): string;
var
  NpWnd, NpEdit: HWnd;
  Buffer: string;
  BufLen: Integer;
begin

  Memo1.Clear;
  NpWnd := FindWindow('#32769', nil);
  if NpWnd <> 0 then
  begin
     //NpEdit := FindWindowEx(NpWnd, 0, 'Afx:400000:202b:10003:6:0', nil);
     //if NpEdit <> 0 then
     //begin
        BufLen := SendMessage(NpWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
        SetLength(Buffer, BufLen + 1);
        SendMessage(NpWnd, WM_GETTEXT, BufLen, LParam(PChar(Buffer)));
        Memo1.Lines.Text := Buffer;
     //end;
  end;
end;
```

I used Winspy++ to get all window classes. In Win spy++, different window classes look like below:

[image]

I tried all window classes under Extra.exe . But nothing seems to be able to get me the text from terminal window. Could anyone please provide me some tips to identify the issue?

Comment: Screen scraping is probably your best bet.

Comment: Probably the "terminal" is not a native control, maybe created using a graphic library or something (just guessing).

Comment: That product page says they offer an API, even as Automation, you could try that.

Comment: What return values do you get from WM_GETTEXTLENGTH and WM_GETTEXT?

Comment: @Blurry the text isn't in an EDIT control

Comment: @blurry, i get the title from window class 'SDImainframe' . It's length is 14. No other windows give any text.

Comment: @jonathan, can you please share some links or so, so that i can take look at this 'screen scraping'. thanks in advance.

Comment: @jims takes a screenshot and use ocr to extract text. But why not use the api?

Comment: @Dave, I do not want to use the API, because i like my application to be generic one that can be used across multiple terminal emulators like TN3270, Rumba, extra attachamte, IBM PCOM etc.. If i start using the API, my application will be tied to Extra attachmate..

Do you know good OCR library (Free /commercial) that has reasonable response time?

Comment: Using the Extra API won't tie your program to Extra unless you choose to use that API *exclusively*. So don't choose that. Use the Extra API to talk to Extra, and use other methods to talk to other applications.

Comment: @jimsweb `WM_GETTEXT` copies the text *that corresponds to a window* into a buffer, not the text *being displayed*. It won't return a text that has been displayed using `DrawText` for example. But there is hope if the *Xtra extreme* output window is cmd-based. Can you tell me if you have *cmd* also running whenever you run *extreme* ? In this case, you will be able to use the console functions `AttachConsole`, `ReadConsoleOutput`, etc. to read the text.

Comment: no. Command window never runs along with this emulator.